# React native vector icon not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am using react native version 0.67.3

I install vector icon and i add andriod/app/build.gradle
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

but icon not showing

Answer (score 10):

Use the latest version

```
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
```

You can add latest version of it by below command:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons@latest
```

**For Android,**

write below line in your **android -> app  -> build.gradle**

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'FontAwesome.ttf', 'MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf', 'Ionicons.ttf'] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

**For iOS,**

```
cd ios & pod install
```

**Use**

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

**Note**: Give exact icon name from https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but when I use

```
<Text><Ionicons/><Text>
```

Icons will show in navigation bar.