# Cannot find symbol in react-native-vector-icon

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am getting "Cannot find symbol" in react native vector icons library.

Here is the log i am getting

C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\rn-main\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:29: error: cannot find symbol

import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

^

symbol: class VectorIconsPackage

location: package com.oblador.vectoricons

C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\rn-main\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:82: error: cannot find symbol

new VectorIconsPackage()

^

symbol: class VectorIconsPackage

location: class PackageList

2 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.

I tried to clean gradle cache and npm cache but it didn't worked

Comment: might slove your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390942/react-native-vector-icon-not-showing/71392387#71392387